# Why is this code not working when i use 23 as input?

Tags: c

The goal of the code is to find the smallest possible multiple composed of only 9s and 0s of a positive integer. Don't know why it works for all numbers smaller than 23 but not 23. All help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    int n, check, i, numlen, j, digit;
    i = 2;
    check = 0;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    while(check == 0){
        numlen = 0;
        n = n * i/(i-1);
        j = n;
        while(j > 0){
            j /= 10;
            numlen++;
        }
        j = n;
        while(numlen > 0){
            digit = j % 10;
            j = j / 10;
            numlen --;
            check = 1;
            if (!(digit == 0 || digit == 9)){
                numlen = 0;
                check = 0;
            }
        }
        i ++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", n);
}
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are trying to calculate, but it sounds that the result is overflowing the `int` type.

Comment: Rewriting the`while()`loops into `for()` loops would make the thing more readable.

Comment: you should separate the loop `while(numlen > 0)` in a distinct function and provide an eloquent name for this function -- `check_digits_09` for example -- to make things clearer about what you tru to do

Comment: Anyway, I would go with the opposite approach - generate all of the numbers composed of `9`s and `0`s and check which one is divisible by the input.

Comment: Your way to compute the multiples of _n_ is wrong, this is why the result is not correct for 23 etc, see my answer

Comment: OT:  When the parameters to `main()` are not going to be used, either: 1) use the signature: `int main( void )`  or 2) the first two lines in the body should be: `(void)argc;` and `(void)argv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way to compute the multiples of *n* doing `n = n * i/(i-1);` is wrong, so for at least 23 you imagine you find a multiple of 23 composed of 0 and 9 but that number is not a multiple of 23.

A corrected version from your proposal checking the multiple of *n* up to a solution can be :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int n;

  if ((scanf("%d", &n) == 1) && (n > 0)) {
    int multn;

    for (multn = n; ; multn += n) {
      /* only 9 and 0 ? */
      int j;

      for (j = multn; j > 0; j /= 10) {
        int digit = j % 10;

        if ((digit != 0) && (digit != 9))
          break;
      }
      if (j == 0)
        /* only 9 and 0 ! */
        break;
    }

    printf("%d -> %d (remainder = %d)\n", n, multn, multn%n);
  }
}
```

Compilation and executions:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra m.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
1
1 -> 9 (remainder = 0)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
2
2 -> 90 (remainder = 0)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
3
3 -> 9 (remainder = 0)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
23
23 -> 990909 (remainder = 0)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
32
32 -> 900000 (remainder = 0)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
11111111
11111111 -> 99999999 (remainder = 0)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
12345678
12345678 -> 9900900 (remainder = 9900900)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Note : the last try produces an overflow (*int* are on 32b) and the result is wrong, but there is no guaranty the program ends in case of an overflow.